# How to use JQuery for updating another element's content

Tags: jquery, function, hover

Ok, so I have a list of about 5 links, one after another. When I hover over one of these links, I need it to expand in size (to distinguish it from the others). And when I click on one of these links, I want it to update the image within a different  element. I have figured out how to do this for a singular link using JQuery and CSS, but I am wondering if I need to create 4 additional (for the 4 other links) sets of JQuery functions, or if there is a way to conserve codespace by using for loops with a counter of sorts.
         My issue with the logic (of using just one all-encompassing function) stems from the fact that I do not know how to distinguish between links once they are hovered over. This makes me think I need a different set of functions for each link. Any and all advice is sincerely appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div class="interestsMarquee">

  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" id="interest1" alt="sports" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" id="interest2" alt="music"  />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" id="interest3" alt="hunting" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" id="interest4" alt="exercise" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" id="interest5" alt="shopping" />
  </div>
```

Here is my JQuery code:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
var i = '1';

    $("#interest"+i).hover(function()
   {
     $("#interest"+i).css("width","115%")
               .css("height","70px")
               .css("margin-left","-10px");
    },function()
{
    $("#interest"+i).css("width","95%")
               .css("height","56px")
               .css("margin-left","3px");
        }); 

     $('.trigger').css('cursor', 'pointer')
         .click({id: 'myImage'}, changeImage);

function changeImage(e)
    {
var element=document.getElementById(e.data.id)
if (element.src.match("images/Cowboys.jpg")) 
{
    element.src="images/Countryside_bg.jpg";
    }
   else
   {
   element.src="images/Cowboys.jpg";
     }

    }

   });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use loops or additional `JQuery` functions on this case, with one selector you can match all the elements that you need. Also you shouldn't merge jQuery with pure Javascript code if you don't need. I rewrite your code, now is all in jQuery:

#### The HTML:

```
<div class="interestsMarquee">
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" data-index="1" id="interest1" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" data-index="1" id="interest2" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" data-index="1" id="interest3" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" data-index="1" id="interest4" />
  <img src="sportsInterest.png" class="trigger" data-index="1" id="interest5" />
</div>
```

#### The Jquery:

```
$(".interestsMarquee img").hover(function(){
    $(this).css(
          "width":"115%",
          "height":"70px",
          "margin-left":"-10px"
        );
    },function(){
    $(this).css(
         "width":"95%",
         "height":"56px",
         "margin-left":"3px");
}).click(function(){
    //Lets get the index of the img
    var index = ($(this).data('index');
    var src = "images/default_img.jpg";
    //Switch index to update src
    switch (index ) {
       case (1): src = 'images/image1.jpg';
                 break;
       case (2): src = 'images/image2.jpg';
                 break;
       case (3): src = 'images/image3.jpg';
                 break;
       case (4): src = 'images/image4.jpg';
                 break;
       case (5): src = 'images/image5.jpg';
                 break;
     }
     //adding the new src to the #myImage div
     $('#myImage').attr('src', src);
 });
```

#### The changes:

- Like you are using `.css` you can push `click()` event after `hover` to match the same selector
- Use `$(this)` when you are inside a event function
- You can use `attr('src')` to get the `src` attribute.
- Change multiple css properties in once steep

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sHxR3/

**Update:** I have updated my code to change the outer div img `src` depending of the clicked img.

Comment: Thanks for the help y'all, now I can hover over every one of the links individually and they expand (distinguishing themselves from the other links not being hovered over). Much appreciated. However, I would also like for the links I click on, that each different link will change the

Comment: `<img id="myImage" </img>` to a different image. I realize that this objective was not obviously apparent from my original question and I apologize. I also forgot to let you know (sorry @Tom Sarduy) that the <img> that would be changed was not the link image, but an image in a separate <div>. I was able to fix that easily, though, by just changing the `$(this)` to the actual id I wanted to alter. I think @silver99 may be on to something with the `.each()` function. However, I'm not sure where to take it from there.

Comment: @Connor: You can change another element `src` from the same `.interestsMarquee img` click event, like you said using the `$('myImage')` selector. Still Nn need to use `each()` on this case.

Comment: @TomSarduy I realize that Tom, but what can I do if I want to distinguish between the click events for the different`.interestsMarquee` images. There are 5 of the images in the `<div>` list, and I want the first image to change the `$('myImage') to one certain image. I want the second image in the list (when clicked) to change the `$('myImage') to a different image than what occurred in the first scenario. Does that make sense? Sorry I am probably misunderstanding your advice, but that is my issue.

Comment: oh, I see... best way to go is to add a `data-index` property to every `img` with value 1,2,3,4,5, then you can get that index using `$(this).data('index')`, I had updated my answer with the new code.

Comment: @TomSarduy Thank you very much for your continued help. That is exactly what I was looking for. I am very impressed with the community at stackoverflow.

Comment: @Connor: Good to know. I'm impressed too, come back soon with a nice question :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and answer your question by showing how you can improve your jQuery code and how to solve your problem in one go! :)

First off, you can simplify your code by refactoring the `.css()` calls into one call.
This will make the entire code go faster since you wont be looping over the same element for each call of `.css()`.

So that piece of code would go from

```
$("#interest"+i).hover(function() {
  $("#interest"+i).css("width","115%")
         .css("height","70px")
         .css("margin-left","-10px");
},function() {
  $("#interest"+i).css("width","95%")
         .css("height","56px")
         .css("margin-left","3px");
});
```

to

```
$("#interest"+i).hover(function() {
  $("#interest"+i).css({
    "width":"115%",
    "height":"70px",
    "margin-left":"-10px"
  });
},function() {
  $("#interest"+i).css({
    "width":"95%",
    "height":"56px",
    "margin-left":"3px"
  });
});
```

and lastly, and Adil beat me to it, you can bind the hover event to a  class instead.
And following his advice with the selectors as well are very good! :)

Hope this helps some! :)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the JQuery .each() function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: `each()` function is not needed on this case

Comment: @TomSarduy Sorry man I thought each() might help fix the problem after looking at the example code. Could you explain an alternative solution to my question in the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".interestsMarquee img").hover(function(){
            $(this).css({"width":"115%", "height":"70px", "margin-left":"-10px"});
        },function(){
            $(this).css({"width":"95%", "height":"56px", "margin-left":"3px"});
        }).click(function(){
            src = $("#myImage").attr("src");
            if(src == "images/Cowboys.jpg"){
                $("#myImage").attr("src", "images/Countryside_bg.jpg");
            }else{
                $("#myImage").attr("src", "images/Cowboys.jpg");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="interestsMarquee">
    <img src="sportsInterest.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="sports" />
    <img src="sportsInterest.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="music"  />
    <img src="sportsInterest.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="hunting" />
    <img src="sportsInterest.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="exercise" />
    <img src="sportsInterest.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="shopping" />
</div>

<img id="myImage" src="images/Cowboys.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!